# HTTP fetch request makes my app crash on React native only when Wi-Fi is not connected

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

Intiially I had the issue of HTTP request I solved it by adding permissions in androidmanifest now my app crashes when not connected to Wi-Fi or data

I also added these lines in my dependencies
`api(platform("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-bom:4.7.2")) api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp") api("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor")`

Comment: What is the stacktrace for the crash

Comment: I'm seeing the logs but it doesn't show something useful. Everything works perfect in the debug mode though @PPartisan

Answer (score 0):

You're either not catching the exception thrown by the fetch request or there's code that exists after the request that is failing due to the necessary data not being retrieved. Providing a stacktrace would be useful but ultimately what it comes down to is correctly catching HTTP request failures with something like this:

```
fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      // logic to perform if the request succeeds
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error); // catching the error and handling it the way you see fit.
    }); // retrieved from https://reactnative.dev/docs/network

// executing the rest of the function/program without relying on what happens 
// in the fetch request due to the nature of promises.
```

On the other hand, if you're synchronizing the execution and awaiting the response to be retrieved, you should handle (in the catch probably) the possibility that the request would fail in a way that doesn't break the rest of your code.

Comment: The catch is working well. As the application is totally fine in the Debug mode

Comment: Then please provide a stacktrace of what the error is exactly. Your question is too vague at it stands and there's a lot of possibilities for what could be causing your errors, one being my response (which apparently is not it).

Comment: How can I see stack trace when the application is in release mode? When I made a debug APK it is working good

Comment: You never mentoned that the issue only exists when run in release mode. Would probably be useful to include that in the original question for clarity.

Comment: Most people use a tool like Crashlytics to capture crash logs in production @TalalAlam

Comment: Thankyou for the support. My bad :(